# Angular-CLI proxy losing path

Tags: angular, proxy, command-line-interface

I have the following content inside my proxy.config.json which is being passed to ng serve via --proxy-config proxy.config.json.

```
"/api/*": {
"target":"http://myserver.com",
"secure": false,
"pathRewrite": {"^/api" : ""},
"changeOrigin": true,
"logLevel": "debug"
```

}

Suppose a GET from angular was http://localhost:4200/api/auth.  Here is what I see in the console

[HPM] GET /api/auth -> http://myserver.com

What is happening to the /auth?

Answer (score 0):

That's normal behavior of Angular-CLI proxy. It works, just displays the wrong information but makes a request correctly.